# What is the correct order?

Tags: grammar, word-order

I'd like to know the correct order of this sentence:

Is it:

> I and my friends plan for a movie months before the release.

or

> My friends and I plan for a movie months before the release.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct version is "My friends and I plan for a movie months before the release". "I" always follows the first subjects.